# Values are not updating from Index.php to example.php

Tags: php, if-statement, include, require

Values are not passing when the files are included. Even i tried `global $subidone;` and `$subidone = $_GET['subidone'];` but not working

**Index.php Code :**

```
if (isset($_GET['adgroup_id']) && $_GET['adgroup_id'] == "123") {
    
    $subidone = "Canada";
    $file = ["example.php", "sample.php"];
    $randomFile = $file[array_rand($file)];
    include $randomFile;    
    
}
```

**Example.php code :**

```
//global $subidone;
//$subidone = $_GET['subidone'];
$affurl="https://example.com?subid1=" . $subidone ."&subid2=123456";
echo $affurl;
```

**Output i want :** `https://example.com?subid1=Canada&subid2=123456`

**Output i am getting :** `https://example.com?subid1=&subid2=123456`

Comment: Do you have an `adgroup_id` in your URL? If so, what is its value?

Comment: I agree with @LajosArpad because it seems fine when I tried your code.

Comment: The code works under the pre-condition that the file is included after the $subidone variable has been initialized. while the code in _index.php_ code does initialize $subidone, the code in _example.php_ does not. Therefore it looks like that the output you don't want can be created by directly requesting _example.php_ instead of _index.php_. However requesting _index.php_ with the right get parameters should produce the wanted output. Compare with the two previous comments, I can also confirm the code works. I also left an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Including files in PHP can lead to unexpected effects if the input conditions aren't checked upfront. Then it is easy to directly open the file in the browser (it requests it) which is not intended.

This issue is common when the include file is a standard PHP file within the public directory (webroot).

What you could do is to verify the pre-condition and if it is violated, then throw.

In your example the `$subidone` variable is the precondition and it must be a string:

*example.php* code:

```php
<?php # start of file
// verify pre-condition for this include file
if (!is_string($subidone ?? null)) {
    throw new ErrorException('bad file include: ' . basename(__FILE__));
}


$affurl="https://example.com?subid1=" . $subidone ."&subid2=123456";
echo $affurl;
```

Now, whenever the *echo* statement is executed you know at least that the variable *$subidone* was passed as a string, which is the pre-condition of that files' code to work. And you know when it was not as the code throws and stops early.

This also prevents you searching in the wrong places if there are issues with the inclusion or the variable.

It depends a bit, however normally the include files don't belong into the public webroot so that you know they can only be included by another php file, not directly requested by the browser.